Reduction For MAC systems
I am not too knowledgeable regarding reductions for message authentication code encryption. Here is an example I found:
There is a MAC' based on a preliminary existing MAC as such:
MAC'(k, m) = MAC(k,m) || MAC(k, m). we want to prove that if MAC is a secure MAC algorithm, then MAC' also is.
So I created the contrapositive:
If MAC'(k, m) = MAC(k, m)||MAC(k, m) is NOT a secure algorithm, then MAC(k, m) must also NOT be a secure algorithm.
Can someone explain to me how to get to a final reduction algorithm. Can you write it in similar format to this reduction wrote for PRGs: 
Also, I know for PRGs, a not secure one would be saying there exists a distinguisher that would be able to distinguish between the PRG and a uniform string with a polynomial probability. What would be the equivalent in MAC terms? Thanks
